# CardLayout remove old panels when updating information

Tags: java, swing

I'm utilizing CardLayout to switch between two windows. The first window displays the information and the second window edits the information and saves it. The way I've been updating the information is creating a new JPanel every time I click Edit or Save. However, I want to delete the old panel that was created. I've been trying

```
containerPanel.remove(0),
```

and also

```
 Component c = containerPanel.getComponent(0)
 cardlayout.removeLayoutComponent(c);
```

but nothing seems to work when I iterate through the jpanel and check how many components there are. This has been frustrating me for a long while and I'm really stuck.

Comment: Why not just simply reset the panel state (ie re-seed it values each time it is displayed)?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Re-instantiate your "panel state" so that it only contains the components you'd like to be there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - I'm pretty new to CardLayout and swing in general.

Comment: Instead of creating a new "edit" panel every time, use a single "edit pane" whose values can be changed based on your needs

Comment: Okay, I appreciate the suggestion, but I don't think that's an option.

Comment: can you add code for which component are you applying the `CardLayout` and your code where you are adding a panel to the component with the `CardLayout`

Comment: 1) Use only 2 panels, as mentioned by @MadProgrammer.  The `CardLayout` class is good in that it allows us to *avoid* all this nonsense of removing components and adding new ones! 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

When initializing a JPanel (or any Component) that you would like to remove later, store a reference to it using a variable. You will then be able to call `superComponent.remove(subComponent)` to remove it. If necessary, you can then continue the pattern, setting the variable containing the old component to a new one.

For example:

```
JPanel containerPanel = new JPanel();

JPanel subPanel = new JPanel(); // Store a reference to the first panel.
containerPanel.add(subPanel);
containerPanel.remove(subPanel); // Remove the panel like so.

subPanel = new JPanel(); // Set subPanel to the new panel.
containerPanel.add(subPanel);
containerPanel.remove(subPanel); // Repeat as needed.
```